# Embed javascript in Xaringan presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, presentation, xaringan

I have an interactive pooling question created using [polleverywhere](https://www.polleverywhere.com/) that would like to insert into my Xaringan rmarkdown presentation:

```
<script src="https://www.polleverywhere.com/multiple_choice_polls/U43TXrlame7hw6J/web.js?height=250&results_count_format=percent&width=300"></script>
```

What is the right approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You need the `<iframe>` code instead. 
Go to your poll at polleverywhere then click on "3. Present" > Share > Embed poll. There will be a place that says "Copy and paste this snippet into your web page or blog". Copy a code that would look like:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.polleverywhere.com/multiple_choice_polls/XXX" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

and enter this to your slide. Just a note that open your `html` output in a browser like Chrome and not the Viewer pane in RStudio because the latter doesn't show it.

Alternatively if you want people to answer the question without leaving the presentation slide you can embed it as

```
<iframe src="https://PollEv.com/multiple_choice_polls/XXX/web" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

replacing src url from "Shareable response link". It works from Chrome but Firefox seems to squish a bit. Users have to identify who they are first though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I think you are referring to "displaying the reuslts" (Live Chart Widget called by polleverywhere), which use the iframe. What I want is the pooling itself (i.e. so that people can live click on the webpage without leaving the presentation and submit their responses). Polleverywhere calls it Web Response Widget, which is implemented using a js.

Comment: Right I see. I got something working but it's not using a js. I'll append it to the post so maybe try that?

Comment: If you want the js solution, can you tell me where the "Web Response Widget" can be found? I don't see it and quick google didn't reveal it.

Comment: If you go to: https://www.polleverywhere.com/multiple_choice_polls/XXX/embed, ("XXX" should be replaced by the id of the polling question), in the first section you will find "Web Response Widget"). I configured mine as a multiple choice question. I actually posted the embedded code generated by polleverywhere in my original question. Here is an FAQ page from their website: https://www.polleverywhere.com/support/articles/sharing-publishing/embed